# Request method working on blade but not on VUE template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have `{{ \Request::get('sample_parameter') }}` from blade template. Trying to convert it to Vue but its not working. Try using axios using `axios.get('sample_parameter')` but return me an html code.

Using Request::get method in blade template gave me an object response. Also found out that 'sample_parameter' is not existing in API. But in blade file it is being called. I wonder how.

Comment: `Request::get('sample_parameter')` will return a parameter with that name from the request e.g. if `sample_parameter` is part of the query string. `axios.get('sample_parameter')` will perform a `GET` request to the current url + `sample_parameter`. The two methods are not interchangeable.

Comment: Is `sample_parameter` part of the query string?